# How to store invalid UTF-8 text inside Sqlite3 from Python?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

Sqlite3 itself doesn't have a problem storing invalid UTF-8 sequences as text. Python on the other side will throw by default when an invalid UTF-8 sequence is encountered. To work around that Python has the functions `os.fsdecode` and `os.fsencode` that can take any byte sequence and produce a Python string. However those strings can cause trouble.

To retrieve an invalid UTF-8 text out of a database with **python-sqlite** one can set  `.text_factory` to a function that handles the conversion from bytes from the database to a Python string:

```
import sqlite3, os
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.text_factory = os.fsdecode
```

However when it comes to storing a string produced by `os.fsencode` Python throws:

```
import sqlite3, sys, os
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.text_factory = os.fsdecode
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE foo(bar TEXT)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES(?)", [os.fsdecode(b"\xff")])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pysqlite_unicode_bug.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES(?)", [os.fsdecode(b"\xff")])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcff' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Is there an analogue to `.text_factory` that handles the encoding instead of the decoding of the Python string?

As a workaround I currently convert the Python string to bytes myself and then cast it back to TEXT on the Sqlite site:

```
invalid_str = os.fsdecode(b"\xff")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES(cast(? AS TEXT))", [os.fsencode(invalid_str)])
```

This works, but it leads to a lot of `os.fsencode` and `cast()` all over the place. Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why would you want to store invalid strings?

Comment: To store filenames on Linux, which aren't restricted to UTF-8. Furthermore storing them as BLOB, instead of TEXT, in the database would disable all Sqlite3 text functionality (e.g. glob matching requires TEXT to work).

Comment: If you had a custom class, you could use `register_adapter()`.